Cannot Remove Migration in EF Core 8 Seed Data: The seed entity ... cannot be added because a default value was provided for the required property
Using the EF Core 8 command line utility to remove a seed data migration, I get this error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'MyDbContext'. The exception 'The seed entity for entity type 'User' cannot be added because a default value was provided for the required property 'Id'. Please provide a value different from '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

However it allowed me to Add-Migration just fine.
My (messed up) migration:
 public partial class TestUserData : Migration
 {
     /// <inheritdoc />
     protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
     {
         migrationBuilder.InsertData(
             table: "Users",
             columns: new[] { "Id", "AdFreePeriodStartedOn", "Email", "RemainingLLMTokens", "RemainingLikes", "RemainingMatchOptions", "RemainingSuperLikes", "UserName", "Address" },
             values: new object[] { new Guid("0001c288-26e8-4926-852f-300408706319"), null, "VALID EMAIL", 0, 0, 0, 0, "TestUser", null });
     }

     /// <inheritdoc />
     protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
     {
         migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
             table: "Users",
             keyColumn: "Id",
             keyValue: new Guid("0001c288-26e8-4926-852f-300408706319"));
     }
 }

How do I remove this stuck migration with incorrect seed data?
